# Repeated use of an alias within a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I am trying to append a column created by using `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` to the original selection that was counted. However, the selection is pretty complex (much more than the `WHERE ...` line I've included in my example) so I'd rather not duplicate the code.

SQL Server doesn't approve of my using an alias `t1` inside of the left join statement. Any suggestions?

---

```
select t1.school, t1.grade,t1.individual,t2.cnt as 'class size' from (
        select * from students
        where (students.age < 16 and students.ACT_score is not null)
) as t1
left join (
    select distinct school, grade, count(*) as 'cnt' from t1
    group by school, grade
) as t2
on t1.school = t2.school and t1.grade = t2.grade
```

---

Comment: You reference column `subjects.ACT_score`, but not table `subjects`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's 2005 or newer, use a CTE:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
<Your complicate query here>
)
SELECT fields
FROM MyCTE
JOIN (subquery referencing MyCTE)
...
```

Comment: This seems to work great. I've never used `with` before, do I need to drop anything or does it act as an alias?

Comment: @Mr. Dave - a CTE is basically a view that is only good for one query.  There's no need to drop or anything like that.

Comment: Make sure you do two things when using a CTE: 1) place a semi-colon after any statements right before the `WITH` (a lot of people put it right before, like this : `;WITH`) and 2) you must `SELECT` from the `WITH` immediately after declaring it.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to maintain if you use COUNT(*) with an OVER clause as follows:

```
with cntAppended as (
  select
    *,
    count(*) over (partition by school, grade)
  from students
)
  select
    school, 
    grade,
    individual,
    cnt as "class size"
from cntAppended
where (age < 16 and ACT_score is not null)
```

Don't be tempted to avoid WITH and putting the WHERE clause in one query with COUNT. If you do, you will only count students in each school and grade who are < 16 and have ACT scores. It looks like you want to count all students for the [class size] column, but only see data for certain ones in your result.

If and when T-SQL [supports the QUALIFY keyword](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/532474/qualify-request-for-a-new-filtering-clause), queries like this may be even easier:

```
select
  school, 
  grade,
  individual,
  count(*) over (partition by school, grade) as "class size"
from students
QUALIFY (age < 16 and ACT_score is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your query in a simpler form, no CTE needed:

```
SELECT t1.school
    ,t1.grade
    ,t1.individual
    ,t2.cnt AS 'class size'
FROM students t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT school
        ,grade
        ,count(*) AS 'cnt'
    FROM students 
    GROUP BY school, grade
) AS t2 ON t1.school = t2.school
        AND t1.grade = t2.grade
WHERE t1.age < 16
    AND t1.ACT_score IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I believe the `FROM t1` is the culprit. The error message states : "Invalid object name 't1'."

Comment: Oops, copy and paste error. t1 is supposed to be `students` - fixed it in my answer.